# sshd_config AllowGroups has no effect

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, users, group, sshd

I'm trying to secure a new sever for a clients app. What I'm trying to achieve is to lock down ssh access to users within a certain group.

I have created my group 'remote' and a new user to that group called remoteuser; if I cat /etc/group I see

```
remote:x:823:remoteuser
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I added the option

```
AllowGroups remote
```

from the `sshd_config` man page, this should restrict login to only users in 'remote' group.

After restarting sshd I try login with another user and I am prompted for the password. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

I am using Ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score 8):

You are prompted for a password, but even if you would provide correct password, you would not be granted access. This is how this option works.

It is another level of secrecy, that the server is not leaking the list of users that have valid account. If it would not do that, attacker could scan the server for valid users in minutes and attack only the existing users, which he can expect to have weak password or whatever else guess.

Comment: yep correct should of tailed auth.log and says user is not in the allowed group

Answer (score 2):

I will venture an educated guess that 'AllowGroups' prevents users from other groups from logging in, not from seeing the login prompt.

This is smarter from a security standpoint, otherwise an attacker could use to existence of the login prompt to brute-force analyse who belongs to the group.

You might consider blocking password logins altogether with 'PasswordAuthentication no'

Comment: yep correct should of tailed auth.log and says user is not in the allowed group